# Appened Query and Filter Variables to Output in Oracle OBIEE

Tags: excel, database, oracle, obiee

I frequently use OBIEE to create custom analyses from predefined subject areas. I'm often making extensive use of filters as I'm typically pulling data on a very specific issue from a huge dataset. A problem I have repeatedly come across is trying to recreate a previous analyses complete with the filter variables.

Obviously if it's something I know I'll come back too, I'll save the query. But that's often not the case. Maybe a month or two will go by and I'll need to generate a new version of a previous report to compare with the original and I end up not being able to trust the output because I'm not sure that it's using the same variables.

Is there a way to append the query and filter variables to the report itself so it can be easily referenced and recreated?

Additional info. 
 * I almost exclusively output the data from OBIEE as a .csv and do most of the work from excel pivot tables I save in .xlsx. 
 * I'm not a DBA.

Answer (score 2):

a) You can always save filters as presentation catalog objects instead of clicking them together from zero every single time. Think LEGO bricks for adults. OBIEE is based on the concept of stored and reusable objects.

b) You will never have your filters in your CSV output since CSV is a raw data output and not a formatted / graphical one. If you were using a graphical analysis export you could always add the "Filters View" to your results.

Long story short since you're using OBIEE as a data dump tool and are circumventing what the tool is designed to do and how it is supposed to function you're constraining yourself in terms of the benefits and the functionality you can get from it.

Comment: That last sentence - just amazing.

Comment: "amazing" as in what? Obvious?

Comment: Thank you very much. So it's a clear no-go based on how I've been using OBIEE. Can you expand a bit on what you mean by graphical analysis export? Do you just mean exporting as pdf/pptx file types? Or is this something within OBIEE itself? 
I've always used .csv exports just because it's dead simple for me to dump it into excel, manipulate and then easily share the data form there.

Comment: Meaning using OBIEE analyses with different views including one "Filters View". It's a standard, out-of-the-box view type. My amin instance is rebooting at the moment, so I can't screenshot it right now but here's the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/filter.htm#BIEUG131

Comment: Alternatively you can also save the logical SQL (LSQL) of the analysis you've built and use it at a later stage again: https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obis/logical_sql/logical_sql

Comment: Obvious yes, but said so well.

Comment: Ok back up. Here's two screenshots of the Filters view and the LSQL view:
https://imgur.com/uC8LySW
https://imgur.com/QtY4GeE

Comment: That's perfect. Let me play around and see what I can do. I've messed with some of that before but my experience was that it was somewhat clunky when I was dealing with 100k+ line reports.